# ECS Fargate service discovery

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate, aws-security-group, aws-cloudmap

I am using AWS ECS Fargate, I am currently using service discovery to allow my tasks to communicate with eachother. I have an issue where my tasks can only communicate if I place this security group on them

```
resource "aws_security_group" "ecs_config_service" {
  name        = "staging-ecs-config-service"
  description = "We need this so our services can communicate"
  vpc_id      = module.vpc.vpc_id

  ingress {
    from_port = 0
    to_port   = 0
    protocol  = "-1"
    cidr_blocks = [
      "0.0.0.0/0"
    ]
  }
}
```

If I remove this security group and only allow traffic from my load balancer the containers can't communicate. This feels like a bit of a security risk allowing traffic from anywhere but I'm not sure how else I can allow my tasks to communicate.

My ECS cluster sits within a private subnet in my VPC.

Is there something I am missing with my setup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of whitelisting IP addresses, you should try whitelisting security groups. For example if you have two separate services running in ECS, you could assign Security Group A to the first service, and Security Group B to the second service, and create a rule in Security Group A that allows ingress from Security Group B.

---

Alternatively, you could at least restrict the IP range to the CIDR block of your VPC so that nothing outside the VPC would be able to access your services.